# how to share url on linkedin with https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url=http without error

Tags: html, api, linkedin-api

when the user clicks on the share button it is redirected to the error screen that I printed below. for some urls they work others don't. follows URL that redirects to error page:

https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url=https://toprecursoshumanos.tweezer.jobs//candidato/vaga/ver_vaga/1521553e-e2f6-4d7b-bf38-c34aac37c303

I consulted the post inspector and inspected the url everything seems fine, it complains about the description but I also increased it to more than 100 characters.

Comment: my cod : <a class="social_link dropdown-item" title="{{ TEXTOS.compartilhar_linkedin }}"
          target="_blank"
          href="https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url={{ vaga.get_link_publicar }}">
        <i class="fa fa-linkedin" style="color:#007BB5;"></i>
        <span><strong class="text-muted">{{ TEXTOS.linkedin }}</strong></span>
       </a>

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two issues:

1. You have two forward slashes after "jobs" in your URL.
2. Your URL needs to be URL-encoded. Currently it isn't.

Comment: I encoded and removed the duplicate slash, the same error remains. some site url work others don't.